# make http request and redirect using ci

Tags: json, http, codeigniter-3

i want to ask about html request on CI so i have some questions.

1. i have data for example in view

> ```
>     <?php
>       foreach($data_gw as $user){
>     ?>      
>       <td><?php  $user->dt_request_pod; ?></td>
>      <?php } ?>
> <br>
>     <?php
>      $test_time = $user->dt_request_pod;
>        ?>
> <br>
>   <?php
>      $new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('1 seconds',strtotime($test_time)));
>      echo  $new_time;
>     ?>
> ```

and now i want to get that $new_time variable ( using redirect on CI ) and get that variable on my controller for example

> `redirect('localhost/2ndpage.php?id=123')`

2. after get that variable i want to make http request with link example

> `http://abcde.com/api/pod/gettrackpartnerresi?key=CD8B025D3335477A8C779FB8BC65FEB8&afterdatetime=2017-07-13`

many thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried with session ?

Comment: not yet , but i use session on login form

Comment: ok set a session variable for $test_time, example  $this->session->set_userdata($test_time) and access the session data in the controller by applying         $session_value = $_SESSION[$test_time]; and you can pass that variable to url

Comment: thats doesn,t work
 
 this is my controller 
 
 public function test_page()
 {
  //$this->load->helper('session');
  //$this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->model('test_model');
  $id = $this->test_model->test_var($id);
  $id = $_SESSION[$id];
  $this->load->view('page1');
 }
 
 this is my models
    function test_var()
    {
     $this->session->set_userdata('$id') ;
    }

Comment: where you setting the session ?

Comment: It seems you are closing `foreach` block before you attempt to use `$user->dt_request_pod` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed i have other way

on controller

```
> public function get_date($new_time)   {
> 
>       $data1['mydate'] = $new_time;       $this->load->view('menu');
>       $this->load->view('page1',$data1);
> 
> 
>       ////test json request
> 
>   $data = array
> 
>    (
>         'cabang'      => '1',
>         'key' => 'a',
>         'kode_cabang'    => 'b',
>         'kodecaodoo'=> '',
>         'kodestatus'=>'',
>         'name'=>'',
>         'noresi'=>'',
>         'note'=>'',
>         'trackingdatetime'=>''
>         );
> 
>     $data_string = json_encode($data);
> 
>     $curl = curl_init('http://mysite.com.ap-southeast-1.compute.xxx.com:8084/api/pod/gettrack');
> 
>     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
> 
>     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
>     'Content-Type: application/json',
>     'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
>     );
> 
>     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  // Make it so the data coming back is put into a string
>     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);  // Insert the data
> 
>     // Send the request
>     $result = curl_exec($curl);
> 
>     // Free up the resources $curl is using
>     curl_close($curl);
> 
>     echo $result;
> 
> 
> 
>   }
```

then on my view just post

> echo $mydate